# Timing requests in MVC5 application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have an MVC 5 WebAPI application and try to estimate, very approximately, the timing of each request, to see what request how many time it took and eventually optimize the most expensive ones.

my code is the following

```
static public int time;
private DateTime start;

protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    start = DateTime.Now;
}

protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    time = start.CompareTo(DateTime.Now);
    var request = ((System.Web.HttpApplication)sender).Request;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($">> MyServices request {request.Path} {request.QueryString} took {TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time)}");            
}
```

However the output is mainly the same:

> MyServices request /MyServices/ZoneBlock/GetZoneBlock
>   contentTypeId=18&blockName=sliderhautauto_slide2 took
>   `-00:00:00.0010000`

the "time" is the same (-00:00:00.0010000) for any request, that seem strange to me...

*PS.*
My application is built on .NET 4.5, so the tools like [MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/AspDotNet) (.NET 4.6.1 min) unfortunately will not work for my case...

Comment: This isn't going to work. You need to remember that this code will service multiple request **at the same time**. Yet you've only got one `time` and your resetting `start` over and over. You'd be better off looking into the HTTP logs in IIS or something similar

Comment: actually I am the only user of the requests, the requests are on my localhost

Comment: Well on that case this isn't going to prove anything at all. It's a totally artificial test. You need to do some research into bench marking

Comment: That doesn't mean the code will work, or that the numbers you'll get will have *any* meaning - the time to service a single request is meaningless. It's the time under *load* that matters. In any case, using `DateTime` for benchmarking won't work either. That type simply doesn't have the required resolution. You'd need a `Stopwatch` at least.

Comment: If you *really* want to measure performance add [Miniprofiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet) to your application

Comment: thanks, is surely interesting to understand that the code has any meaning or will not work, but more interesting is how to do it better....

Comment: @Serge add MiniProfiler or Application Insights. *That's* how you can do this better. If you want to see what needs to be done check MiniProfiler's code - what events does it handle, how it stores timings, how it identifies different requests

Comment: @Serge for example the [ProfilingActionFilter](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/src/MiniProfiler.Mvc5/ProfilingActionFilter.cs) adds an ActionFilter that captures the start and end of a specific action, storing the data in the current context. That "data" in this case is a MiniProfiler `Step` object

Comment: @Serge in any case, what you ask is not trivial and far more complex than simply subtracting two DateTime objects. One could argue that the question is a bit out of topic as it's too broad

Comment: The MiniProfiler is for the .NET 4.6.1 min, my application is for .NET 4.5...

Answer (score -1):

Don't write that yourself,
the time will already be in the log of the application (at least when standard logging settings are used). If you need it more accessible, I like to use miniprofiler.

Comment: The *log* can't be used to measure performance. Miniprofiler or Application Insights don't check the log, they record their own profiling events

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos *sigh* the log can be used to view the numbers. Asp.net collects them for you, no need to reinvent the wheel. If you something which can be customized and displays the result on a webpage, miniprofiler is nice.
AppInsights is also nice, but more complicated

Comment: ASP.NET logging doesn't collect any such numbers. Neither MiniProfiler, nor any other profiler, use the log. You can [verify this yourself](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/src/MiniProfiler.Mvc5/ProfilingActionFilter.cs), MiniProfiler is an open source project. Server logs are used after the fact to calculate statistics like requests per second. The very act of logging is expensive enough to affect profiling